# Remove clicked class by click/on click in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code, all I want is to remove the class that I clicked.

I don't understand why it does not works, I tried both

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".start").on("click", function(){       
    $(this).removeClass("start");
    return false;
  });
});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".start").click( function(){        
    $(this).removeClass("start");
    return false;
  });
});
```

index.php
in a while loop, I have

```
   <li><a href="#" class="start">Name</a> </li>
```

Comment: are you getting any `undefined` error in console?

Comment: Make sure that you have included the jQuery library.

Answer (score 1):

You may have forgotten to add reference of jquery...

This works fine here:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".start").on("click", function(){       
    $(this).removeClass("start");
  });
});
```

```css
.start 
{
    color:black;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


   <li><a href="#" class="start">Name</a> </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the elements are created in while loop may be your class='start' element remains undetected. Try this..

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $(document).on('click','.start',function(){        
            $(this).removeClass("start");
            return false;
         });
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

add jquery library to your code
visit jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Jf8mp/15/`jsfiddle`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on('click','.start',function(){        
        $(this).removeClass("start");
        return false;
     });
  });
```

[**follow this also**](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css_classes.asp)

Comment: @AbuBakkarSiddique welcome!! you can learn more from: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css_classes.asp)